# Plotting using subplot with different x-axis for each plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure, subplot

I am trying to plot figure with three plots inside it using `subplot`. The y-axis for all three plots is same from `-1` to `1` while the x-axis is `2.5`, `5`, and `10` Respectively. The problem that is for all three plots the x-axis looks similar for all of them. I tried to use `axis square` but it changed plots to  a square. I want the first plot to start from the left and end at a point while the second one start from the left and end at a point where it is a double distance of x-axis of the first plot. The third plot must start from the left and end at the point where the x-axis is thripple of the x-axis of the first plot. Is there any way to do that?

This is an example with an empty plot just to show how I want my figure to look like.

I used below code but unfortunately it is not working correctly

```
figure
subplot (3,1,1);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:0.5:2.5)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 2.5]);
ylim([-1 1]);
% axis square
subplot (3,1,2);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:1:5)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 5]);
ylim([-1 1]);
% axis square
subplot (3,1,3);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:2:10)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([-1 1]);
% axis square
```

[image]

Comment: In [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#inputarg_p)'s documentation they [explain this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#zmw57dd0e799267)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Position` property of `axes` (here each of your subplot) and customize them as you wish, using the nomenclature

```
[l b w h]
```

where:

l: left 
b: bottom
w: width
h: height

For example assign a handle to each subplot:

```
h(1) = subplot(3,1,1)
h(2) = subplot(3,1,2)
h(3) = subplot(3,1,3)
```

and change their position (here in normalized units):

```
set(h(1),'Position',[.1 .75 .2 .2])
set(h(2),'Position',[.1 .45 .5 .2])
set(h(3),'Position',[.1 .15 .8 .2])
```

you can also do it in one go as follows:

```
h(1) = subplot(3,1,1,'Position',[.1 .75 .2 .2])
```

etc.

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Though it probably won't make any measurable difference performance-wise, if you're passing the `'Position'` value explicitly anyway there isn't really any need to even use `subplot` over `axes`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use your same code with a slight modification in the subplot command. Try the following:

```
figure
subplot (3,3,1);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:0.5:2.5)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 2.5]);
ylim([-1 1]);

subplot (3,3,4:5);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:1:5)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 5]);
ylim([-1 1]);

subplot (3,3,7:9);
xlabel('x cm')                                              
ylabel('y cm')                                          
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:2:10)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:1:1)
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([-1 1]);
```

It'll give this output:[image]